# How to determine if there was an exception in the handler in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I use handler in my function. How to find out if an exception occurred while executing the handler body?

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ...
END;
```

Comment: *How to find out if an exception occurred while executing the handler body?* An error in the handler won't be handled!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `HANDLER` for your exception and you can set settings or variable values as you like:

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
SET hasError = 1;
```

And later you can check the value of `hasError`.

You can do something more complex as well in stored procedures:

```
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ...
    END;
```